# failed json to java object

Tags: java, json

following code doesn't work. cannot covert JSON to JAVA Object.
how to fix it? thanks.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Rest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{'CBE_GetNewSessionResponse': {'CBE_GetNewSessionResult': '10016-300-0000022151'}}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data.getResponse());
    }
}

class Data {
    private CBE_GetNewSessionResponse response;

    public CBE_GetNewSessionResponse getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public void setResponse(CBE_GetNewSessionResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    class CBE_GetNewSessionResponse{

        private String  CBE_GetNewSessionResult;

        public String getCBE_GetNewSessionResult() {
            return CBE_GetNewSessionResult;
        }

        public void setCBE_GetNewSessionResult(String cBE_GetNewSessionResult) {
            CBE_GetNewSessionResult = cBE_GetNewSessionResult;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Give us a bit more of the trouble your having. What have you tried? what's wrong? ect. You can't just "Here's ma code. Fix it >:( "

Comment: @Vulcan Gson accepts `'` instead of `"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You named field in Data `response` while it's named `CBE_GetNewSessionResponse` in JSon. Try maybe this way

```
public class Rest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "{'CBE_GetNewSessionResponse': {" +
                "'CBE_GetNewSessionResult': '10016-300-0000022151'}" +
                "}";
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
        System.out.println(data.getCBE_GetNewSessionResponse().getCBE_GetNewSessionResult());
    }
}

class Data {
    private CBE_GetNewSessionResponse CBE_GetNewSessionResponse;

    public CBE_GetNewSessionResponse getResponse() {
        return CBE_GetNewSessionResponse;
    }

    public void setResponse(CBE_GetNewSessionResponse response) {
        this.CBE_GetNewSessionResponse = response;
    }

    class CBE_GetNewSessionResponse{

        private String  CBE_GetNewSessionResult;

        public String getCBE_GetNewSessionResult() {
            return CBE_GetNewSessionResult;
        }

        public void setCBE_GetNewSessionResult(String cBE_GetNewSessionResult) {
            CBE_GetNewSessionResult = cBE_GetNewSessionResult;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Also in case you want to have different names in `Data` class fields and JSon keys you would need to implement your own `FieldNamingStrategy` like

```
class MyNameStrategy implements FieldNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public String translateName(Field f) {
        if (f.getName().equals("response")) {
            return "CBE_GetNewSessionResponse";
        } else {
            return f.getName();
        }
    }
}
```

and use it while creating `Gson` object

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingStrategy(new MyNameStrategy()).create();
```

Comment: The getters/setters are not important to `Gson`.

Answer (score 1):

[The `Gson` docs state](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-design-document)

> **Using fields vs getters to indicate Json elements**
>
> Some Json libraries use the getters of a type to deduce the Json
>   elements. **We chose to use all fields** (up the inheritance hierarchy)
>   that are not transient, static, or synthetic. We did this because not
>   all classes are written with suitably named getters. Moreover, getXXX
>   or isXXX might be semantic rather than indicating properties.

In other words, your field needs to be named as it appears in the JSON and vice versa.

```
private CBE_GetNewSessionResponse CBE_GetNewSessionResponse;
```

It will then correctly map your JSON to your object structure.